# SQL Group By With Count Zero

Tags: sql

I have the following query which is not working for my requirement. I need the count zero also returned in the results. I am looking for DocIDs with count zero for the condition specified but those DocIDs are not even showing up in the result.

```
SELECT 
    DocID, Count(*) AS ArchivedCount
FROM 
    Doc
WHERE 
    Status <> 'Archived'
GROUP BY
    DocID
ORDER BY 
    DocID
```

Comment: So you want to count DocIDs that aren't in the table "Doc"? It's possible to do that. But if those DocIDs aren't in "Doc", what table *are* they in?

Comment: Are you sure that DocID is really zero? It might be NULL. In that case you need to use `COUNT(COALESCE(DocID, 0))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to use all `DocID`s, you should use `SUM` in place of `COUNT`, and move the condition into a `CASE` statement inside the `SUM`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    DocID
,   SUM(CASE WHEN Status <> 'Archived' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ArchivedCount
FROM 
    Doc
GROUP BY
    DocID
ORDER BY 
    DocID
```

Now the result is going to contain all `DocID`s, even the ones with the `Status` different from `'Archived'`.

Comment: Can;t get it, because... Sum of zeros gives... zero!

Comment: @MaciejLos But that's what OP is looking for - `DocID`s with the count of zero.